# Circle and line intersecting points

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010, intersection

I'm trying to find the intersecting points where a straight line and a circle intersect. But it is not working for me. Please see the image.

[image: The other two small circles where I should get the intersecting points.]

The other two small circles in the image are where I should get the intersecting points. Following is my Function to calculate intersection.

```html
Private Function FindLineCircleIntersections(ByVal cx As Single, ByVal cy As Single, ByVal radius As Single, ByVal x1 As Single, ByVal y1 As Single, ByVal x2 As Single, ByVal y2 As Single) As Integer
        Dim dx As Single
        Dim dy As Single
        Dim A As Single
        Dim B As Single
        Dim C As Single
        Dim det As Single
        Dim t As Single
        Dim ix1, iy1, ix2, iy2 As Single

        dx = x2 - x1
        dy = y2 - y1

        A = dx * dx + dy * dy
        B = 2 * (dx * (x1 - cx) + dy * (y1 - cy))
        C = (x1 - cx) * (x1 - cx) + (y1 - cy) * (y1 - cy) - _
            radius * radius

        det = B * B - 4 * A * C
        If (A <= 0.0000001) Or (det < 0) Then
            MsgBox("No intersection")
        ElseIf det = 0 Then
            ' One solution.
            t = -B / (2 * A)
            ix1 = x1 + t * dx
            iy1 = y1 + t * dy
            Graphics.FromImage(PictureBox1.Image).FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, ix1 - 2, iy1 - 2, 4, 4)
        Else
            ' Two solutions.
            t = (-B + Sqrt(det)) / (2 * A)
            ix1 = x1 + t * dx
            iy1 = y1 + t * dy
            t = (-B - Sqrt(det)) / (2 * A)
            ix2 = x1 + t * dx
            iy2 = y1 + t * dy
            Graphics.FromImage(PictureBox1.Image).FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, ix1 - 2, iy1 - 2, 4, 4)
            Graphics.FromImage(PictureBox1.Image).FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, ix2 - 2, iy2 - 2, 4, 4)
        End If
    End Function
```

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-LineIntersection.html

Comment: http://www.analyzemath.com/CircleEq/circle_line_intersection.html